# Geolocation to Country Level

Tags: android

I want to be able to determine just what country a person is in (on Android, without using the GPS), so I was thinking to use a web API, that I can call and it will return the country based on the request IP. But I can't find any web API that does this, does any exist?

Comment: A Generic solution would be to find the location irrespective of the users IP Address.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php, which fits all the needs I specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google place API look at [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) just pass the parameters and you will get response in json/xml

Comment: The problem with that is that it seems to require an input. I want the input to just be the request IP, which I don't need to provide as that's just part of the header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453328/get-location-of-wifi-ip-in-android

Answer (score -1):

You need a database to do that and proxy servers will just frustrate your intent

Comment: I don't care if the user tries to fake their IP, or using a proxy to seem that there are somewhere they're not.

Answer (score -1):

Using Cell ID

[OpenCellID API](http://www.opencellid.org/api)

IP based location

[Get location of wifi ip in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453328/get-location-of-wifi-ip-in-android)

Comment: This seems to use the cell tower information, which you don't necessarily need to know. IP address is simpler for my case.

Comment: in that case try this http://www.hostip.info/use.html

Comment: lol *DOWN VOTE* but why? :D